# How to union Invoice data and Reconcile data that is not link directly

Tags: sql, union

**Invoice table**

| DocEntry | ObjType | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 13 | 200 |

**Reconcile table**

| ReconNo | Line | SrcObjType | SrcObjEntry | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 24 | 15 | 150 |
| 1 | 2 | 13 | 11 | 150 |

Link: Invoice.ObjType = Reconcile.SrcObjType
and Invoice.DocEntry = Reconcile.SrcObjEntry

**Expected result:**

| DocEntry | ObjType | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 13 | 200 |
| 15 | 24 | 150 |

I am trying to union the reconcile line that is not link directly to invoice but it is in the same ReconNo with reconciled invoice line. Is this possible in SQL?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Unclear. It *looks* like you're outer-joining the Invoice table to Reconcile table.

Comment: Can you share your coding attempt at this problem? It would be easier for us to help you @SonTran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will get you there?

```
with Invoice  (DocEntry,    ObjType,    Amount) as(
select 11,  13, 200 
),
Reconcile  (ReconNo,Line,SrcObjType,SrcObjEntry,Amount) as(
select 1,1,24,15,150  union all
select 1,2,13,11,150 
),
connection as (
select DocEntry,ReconNo
from Invoice as i
join Reconcile as r on i.DocEntry=r.SrcObjEntry
)
select * from Invoice union all
select SrcObjEntry as DocEntry, SrcObjType as ObjType,Amount
from connection c
join Reconcile r on r.ReconNo = c.ReconNo
where r.SrcObjEntry not in (select DocEntry from invoice)
```

Comment: In order to show data in Reconcile table, can you replace with Invoice table. Expected result will be changed to: 11 | 13 | 150 in stead of 15 | 24 | 150.